# Issue reading RTSP stream with opencv and cv::cvtColor

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, python

I am trying to capture rtsp stream with opencv but it complains about the cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB.
I have done several tries with streaming a different web-camera which working fine but not with the rtsp. The rtsp stream it self is working and tested fine with vlc. The rtsp stream it self is h264 format.

But, if I remark in the lines with the if statement it false, because the frame is empty!

```
import os
import cv2
import time
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from utils.app_utils import FPS, WebcamVideoStream, HLSVideoStream
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-str', '--stream', dest="stream", action='store', type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', dest='video_source', type=int,
                        default=0, help='Device index of the camera.')
    parser.add_argument('-wd', '--width', dest='width', type=int,
                        default=640, help='Width of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-ht', '--height', dest='height', type=int,
                        default=480, help='Height of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-num-w', '--num-workers', dest='num_workers', type=int,
                        default=2, help='Number of workers.')
    parser.add_argument('-q-size', '--queue-size', dest='queue_size', type=int,
                        default=5, help='Size of the queue.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

    input_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)

    print('Reading from webcam.')
    #video_capture = WebcamVideoStream(src="rtsp://ip:port/stream",
    #                              width=args.width,
    #                              height=args.height).start()

    frame_width = args.width
    frame_height = args.height
    print('Width:', frame_width, 'Height:', frame_height)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_test.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))

    vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://ip:port/stream", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = vcap.read()

        #if ret == False:
        #    break

        # Our operations on the frame come here
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        output_q.put(frame_rgb)
        # Convert and store to out file
        #output_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(output_q.get(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        #out.write(output_rgb)
        #cv2.imshow('VIDEO', output_rgb)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame_rgb)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
            
    #video_capture.stop()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which gives me an issue (without if statement):

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._after_fork()
Reading from webcam.
Width: 640 Height: 480
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testRTSP_try.py", line 52, in <module>
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Some more information:

1. Camera footage is from raspberry pi
2. RTSP stream created via:
   `raspivid -o - -t 0 -rot 180 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -b 2000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:<port>/stream}' :demux=h264`
3. RTSP stream monitored via windows vlc

I took a different approach by using motion instead see [How to Make Raspberry Pi Webcam Server and Stream Live Video || Motion + Webcam + Raspberry Pi](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/)

This will setup a http stream instead of a rtsp!

Comment: if ret == False: dont try to use the image, but dont break either. Try reading frames a few times more. After 1000 reads, if no image was captured, break.

Comment: yeah, this didn't helped, it breaks after >1000. Meanwhile the same rtsp stream i am watching via vlc.

Comment: can you try to remove `, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG`? Can you try to open an mp4 file with opencv locally?

Comment: I will try to open mp4 with opencv. Meanwhile I took another way by using motion and instead of rtsp I stream it via http://<ip>:<port>/ and this works!